# How to restore NetBeans IDE window

Tags: windows-10, netbeans-8

The app is running per the following taskbar image:

[image]

but there is no application window.  If I do ALT-TAB, I get the following option:

[image]

Selecting it, shows nothing.

How do I restore the IDE to a normal state?  I've removed and reinstalled NB.  I've removed the cache.  I did not remove the projects folders.

I have only Java 8 installed.

Comment: Win+Left/Up/Right

Comment: This will fix the problem?  If so, post this as an answer.  If the problem appears again, I'll try it.  I like this solution far better, but I won't be able to verify it.

Comment: It's the default Windows shortcut since Windows 7 to force realign the focused window, even offscreen ones (otherwise you could blindly use Alt+Space+X to force maximize).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: All of the following steps may not be necessary.  They are the steps I took that eventually led to normal behavior.

While the app is active per the first image, hit ALT-F.  This will bring up the File menu.  Select "Close All Projects".  NOTE: There is a menu item that maximizes the app window.  This will work for the session only.  Once you restart the app, the same problem will appear.

Delete the cache while the app is running.  There will be some files that will be locked.  Remove as many as you can.  The cache directory can be found by selecting ALT-H About.

Close and restart the IDE.  The app window was restored.